# SpriteKit - Selecting Node After Rotation

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

An SKSpriteNode, named “leaf” is added as a child to another SKSpriteNode, named “allObjects”.

allObjects is set to be the same width and height as the SKView.

I drag the leaf to a location on allObjects and click a distinctive part of its tip and using println get the following in the console.

> touchBegan, touch.locationInNode(allObjects): (621.5, 156.75)
>
> touchesEnded, touch.locationInNode: (621.5, 156.75)
>
> touchesEnded, Leaf location: (695.375, 83.25)
>
> touchesEnded, nodeAtPoint(location).name: **Optional("leaf")**

So far, so good. I can drag the leaf as much as I like at this point with no problem. The important part to note is that the nodeAtPoint is, as expected, ‘leaf’.

However, if I then rotate allObjects, like this:

```
var rotate = SKAction()
rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(0.4, duration: 0)
allObjects.runAction(rotate)
```

… And then click in the same location on the leaf (visually in IOS Simulator), I get the following in the console. I’m confused as to why I have rotated allObjects and clicked in the same location (and get the same co-ordinates) I am no longer selecting the leaf but missing it by a wide margin (nodeAtPoint shows I am hitting the background).

> touchBegan, touch.locationInNode(allObjects): (620.813842773438,
>   156.470306396484)
>
> touchesEnded, touch.locationInNode: (620.813842773438, 156.470306396484)
>
> touchesEnded, Leaf location: (695.375, 83.25)
>
> touchesEnded, nodeAtPoint(location).name: **Optional("allObjects")**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node and coordinates used in the `locationInNode` and `nodeAtPoint` need to be consistent. In this case, the point returned by `locationInNode` is in `allObjects` coordinates while the `nodeAtPoint` call (i.e., `self.nodeAtPoint`) requires a point in scene coordinates. To resolve this, you can either replace

```
nodeAtPoint(location)
```

with

```
allObjects.nodeAtPoint(location)
```

or replace

```
let location = touch.locationInNode(allObjects)
```

with this

```
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
```

Comment: Thank you, @0x141E, that's clear. The first suggestion worked for me: allObjects.nodeAtPoint(location).